# CLion code navigation with C++ doesn't work

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, clion

I've used AppCode (Intellij C++/ObjC IDE that replaces Xcode) for a while and really gotten used to being able to Ctrl+Click on any identifier to get to its definition/decleration.

Now on a new work place, I'm using CLion for a somewhat larger code base and Ctrl+Click hardly ever works. It only seem to work when the identifier is in the same file.

Is there anything I need to setup for this to work correctly? CLion seem to index the code successfully and doing text searches works fine.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use import project functionality of CLion from `File -> Import Project` and give ok for `CMakeLists.txt` file automatic creation. Never mind the file is for CMake, you can build your project with other tools too, but CLion uses it for the dependencies.

Then append in the beginning of that file a line stating:

```
include_directories(.)
```

After that go to `File -> Settings` and there search for `Keymap` from the left and after that on right, right below the word "keymap" there is a selection element for taking for example Eclipse default keymapping in use and there you have at least (I tested only it) the ctrl + click functionality working like charm!!

kudos about the `include_directories(.)` goes to this question: [CLion indexer does not resolve some includes in the project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189910/clion-indexer-does-not-resolve-some-includes-in-the-project-directory)

Answer (score 1):

You  need to  press **ctrl + alt + shift + n**.

And after pressing it a dialog box will appear to enter your variable/function name and click enter.
Tip: Filter the result for a better experience. Filter option is present on right side of the dialog box.

To get a quick peek of function/variable definition press **ctrl + q** while focusing on the variable or function.

To get the detailed or full definition of function press **ctrl + shift + i** while focusing on the variable or function.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at one of my more complicated teaching examples with multiple header/source files where this would come up.

What I see is that ctl-click (and the red/green arrows in the gutter) does work only in the same file. But I can right-click on a method from another file and choose to go to either the declaration (in header) or definition (in cpp).

The hotkeys to do this are not ctl-click. But you can remap hotkeys in IntelliJ ides, so you may be able to come up with hotkey combinations that don't seem too awkward to you.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to run `File` > `New CMake Project from Sources`

Until that point, Ctrl+click in CLion would go to the definitions, but wouldn't find any usages.